# Loop over tests cases in googletest

Tags: c++, loops, testing, googletest, fixtures

I would like to loop over test cases in googleTest. What i call a test case here is this kind of thing:

```
TEST_F(AppsTests, test_wkf1) 
{ 
    //...
}
```

If i loop inside the `TEST_F`, it crashes. So I would a loop on test cases, as in

```
foreach(QString s, list)
{
      TEST_F(AppsName, test_i)
      {
           //...
      }
}
```

I thought of this work around: i do a `SetUp()` and a `TearDown()` inside each loop of the loop. But for doing so, i have to start the test case with `TearDown()` and end it with `setUp()`. which is not nice.

Is there another way, for instance defining an environment above the fixture ?

Comment: Let me see if I got that right: you want to create a test (here named `test_wkf1`) that contains a loop, and you want each iteration of the loop to basically use a freshly initialized resource? What about defining a class that holds the resource and simply create a new instance each time you enter the loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **value-parameterized tests**. Basically, you'd do something like the following:

```
class AppsTests : public ::testing::TestWithParam<QString>
{
    // ...
};

TEST_P(AppsTests, TestA) { /* ... */ }
TEST_P(AppsTests, TestB) { /* ... */ }

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(MyTests, AppsTests, ::testing::ValuesIn(list));
```

After this, you'll generate a test for each value contained in `list`.

Comment: 2019 answer: `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P` is now `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P`